# Problem on upgrading Laravel 9 to Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-9

I am trying to upgrade Laravel 9 to Laravel 10 and I am getting the following error

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/bus[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-webhook-client ^2.8 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-webhook-client[2.8.0, v2.x-dev].
    - webklex/laravel-imap 4.1.2 requires laravel/framework >=5.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/bus[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev, v11.0.0, ..., 11.x-dev], laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/bus and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - spatie/laravel-webhook-client[2.8.0, ..., v2.x-dev] require illuminate/bus ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires webklex/laravel-imap ^4.1 -> satisfiable by webklex/laravel-imap[4.1.2].
```

I have followed the documentation from laravel official document on how to upgrade Laravel 9 to Laravel 10 [text](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade). My composer.json looks like bellow.

```
`{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "php":"^8.0",
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "^4.0",
    "africastalking/africastalking": "^3.0",
    "andreaselia/laravel-api-to-postman": "^1.13",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^1.0",
    "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.13",
    "bschmitt/laravel-amqp": "^2.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
    "guzzlehttp/oauth-subscriber": "^0.5",
    "hedii/artisan-log-cleaner": "^4.1",
    "hubspot/api-client": "^11.0",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
    "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.17",
    "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-webhook-client": "^2.8",
    "spatie/laravel-webhook-server": "^2.0",
    "staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep": "^1.7",
    "stevebauman/location": "^7.0",
    "webklex/laravel-imap": "^4.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.12",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/SmsHelper.php",
      "app/Helpers/CriticalNotification/AirtimeDepletedNotification.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": []
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}`
```

Comment: `spatie/laravel-webhook-client[2.8.0, ..., v2.x-dev] require illuminate/bus ^8.0` how you managed to actually have Laravel 9 is a mystery but you need to update that dependency with one that works for Laravel 10